# adding params to a path defined by a string - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, parameters, link-to

I have the following link that passes parameters to the url, and it works fine.

```
<%= link_to "Buy", new_buyer_path(plan: 'item_D78387628dd', cost:'$45.00'), class: "btn btn-pink", role: "button" %>
```

However, I have a second link that takes its path from a string called raw_cml - raw_cml works fine without the params added.

as an example

```
raw_cml = dashboards/imp/budget_mgmt

<%= link_to "Move", raw_cml(score: '9', question:'8'), class: "btn btn-pink" %>
```

In this example i get the following error:

> undefined method `raw_cml'

Can someone help me move in the right direction?

Comment: It seems as though the path you are trying to go to is not a valid path in your application, Could you please try running `rake routes | grep link` in your terminal and paste the result here? That would tell us more about the routes in your application. (Or you could paste relevant parts of `config/routes.rb` as well)

Comment: see below - I have changed the string name to stop any confusions. All paths are valid. This is an upgrade to a working application.

Comment: `new_buyer_path` is a named route, it's not a string, `link_path` is just a variable storing a string, it just does not work that way, it's just a plain string. Maybe you can work with the URI module to handle the string as an actual URI https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit more research into this and found that .to_params gave a one line approach.

```
<%= link_to "Improve", raw_cml + '?' + { uqr: qid }.to_param, class: "btn btn-pink" %>
```

Seems to be giving the same results.

I'd be interested in any unforeseen consequences of this method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but You can list your available paths of your Rails app like:

```
bundle exec rails routes | grep link
```

to check that `link_path` is ready to use or not.

Comment: Thanks Dac, but link_path is actually a string called raw_cml. i'll edit the question so it is more clear - see its confusing now!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to concat the parameters with the string url:

```
<% fixed_raw_cml = raw_cml + (raw_cml.include?('?') ? '&' : '?') %>
<%= link_to "Move", fixed_raw_cml + { score: '9', question:'8' }.to_query, class: "btn btn-pink" %>
```

Comment: what if `raw_cml` already has a query string? what if it already has an # anchor?

Comment: This seems to have done the trick - thanks. Now, I just need to work out how!